# How do I query my ExtJS grid to see which CheckboxSelectionModel() checkboxes are checked?

Tags: extjs, checkbox, grid

I'm trying to get an ExtJS grid working that has checkboxes from which I can **get an array** of rows/ids so I know which rows have been checked.

I've used [this example from Sencha](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.js) to get the following grid to display correctly with the selection checkboxes, but it doesn't show **how to get the information from the grid** which rows have been checked, e.g. I will have a button that has a handler function and inside this I need to write something like:

var rowIdsChecks = grid.getRowIdsChecked();

**How do I get the information out of the grid which rows are currently checked?**

```
var myData = [
    [4, 'This is a whole bunch of text that is going to be word-wrapped inside this column.', 0.24, '2010-11-17 08:31:12'],
    [16, 'Computer2', 0.28, '2010-11-14 08:31:12'],
    [5, 'Network1', 0.02, '2010-11-12 08:31:12'],
    [1, 'Network2', 0.01, '2010-11-11 08:31:12'],
    [12, 'Other', 0.42, '2010-11-04 08:31:12']
];

var myReader = new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'object',
        type: 'object'
    }, {
        name: 'status',
        type: 'float'
    }, {
        name: 'lastChange',
        type: 'date',
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    }]);

var sm = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    region: 'center',
    style: 'margin: 10px',
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        data: myData,
        reader: myReader
    }),
    cm: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        defaults: {
            width: 120,
            sortable: true
        },
        columns: [
            sm,
            {
                header: 'ID',
                width: 50,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'id',
                hidden: false
            },
            {
                header: 'Object',
                width: 120,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'object',
                renderer: columnWrap

            }, {
                header: 'Status',
                width: 90,
                sortable: true,
                dataIndex: 'status'
            },
            {
                header: 'Last Updated',
                width: 120,
                sortable: true,
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                dataIndex: 'lastChange'
            }]
    }),
    sm: sm,
    viewConfig: {
        forceFit: true
    },
    title: 'Computer Information',
    width: 500,
    autoHeight: true,
    frame: true,
    listeners: {
        'rowdblclick': function(grid, index, rec){
            var id = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelected().json[0];
            go_to_page('edit_item', 'id=' + id);
        }
    }
});
```

## Solution:

Thanks @jujule, this code works:

```
Ext.select('span#internal_link_001').on('click', function() {
    var selections = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
    console.log(selections);
});
```

and then you have the **ids** like this:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [CheckboxSelectionModel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/CheckboxSelectionModel.html) is responsible of tracking and managing selections.

Just use its [getSelections()](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/RowSelectionModel.html#method-Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel-getSelections) method to get an array of selected records :

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the grid has been loaded say a , then use.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ValidateCheckBoxChecked() {
    var count = 0;
    var counter = 0;
    var ChkBoxValue;
    var checkboxList = document.getElementById("divGridData").getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxList.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxList[i].checked) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter; //this will return the number of checkBoxed checked.
}
</script>
```